# Local Font Declaration Not Loading Italic/Bold

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face, webfonts

I know there's plenty of questions on here regarding loading fonts using font face however I have checked them all (or at least a great deal of them) and nothing seems to work...

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
    src: local('Open Sans'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-regular.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {  
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    font-display: swap;
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
    src: local('Open Sans'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-italic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {  
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
    src: local('Open Sans'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-bold.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {  
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
    font-display: swap;
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
    src: local('Open Sans'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-bold-italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/open-sans/open-sans-bold-italic.woff') format('woff');
}
//End Open Sans
```

I then load the script using:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-open-sans', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/scss/css/open-sans.css', false, NULL, 'all');
```

Console throws no 404's and in the Page Source I can see the css file is loaded correctly. However, when attempting to use `font-weight: bold; font-weight: 700; font-style: italic;` nothing happens it just remains normal.

File structure:

```
- theme
    > assets
        > fonts
            > open-sans
                > open-sans-italic.woff
                > open-sans-italic.woff2
        > scss
            > css
                > open-sans.css
```

**Update**

After checking the styles tab of inspector I can see the line is called however, it has a line through it (but is not over ridden anywhere until the default browser `font: inherit` code.

Also to note it correctly bolds in Safari, but not Chrome. Even though both show it crossed out.

The inclusion of both files types means all browsers can serve a font as long as the version is sooner than something like 2014. My chrome is 80.0.3987.132 so I know it's not a version issue.

https://caniuse.com/?search=woff
https://caniuse.com/?search=woff2

**Update**

The issue was fixed by removing `local('Open Sans')`

I have checked my mac and have discovered I have a lot of TTF files installed, with names that don't match. I will not mark an answer as I don't understand why this still doesn't bold for Chrome but does for Safari. Please someone with knowledge of this feel free to answer with detail to claim the bounty.

**Update**

Answer has been provided that means the local declaration can stay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you've told it to look for the same local font file instead of defining the weight/font-style for each instance.

Try to add font-weight/style in `src: local` for example:

```
src: local('Open Sans 400'), //Regular
src: local('Open Sans 400i'), //Regular Italic
src: local('Open Sans 700'), //Bold
src: local('Open Sans 700i'), //Bold Italic
```

or alternatively you could use:

```
src: local('Open Sans'),
src: local('Open Sans Italic'),
src: local('Open Sans Bold'),
src: local('Open Sans Bold Italic'),
```

Comment: Excellent thank you, I've requested an edit to make your answer more detailed and better fit for wider situations if people encounter the same. I can award bounty after 24 hours.

Comment: In my case I have to consider the fact that on most target devices the required fonts are already installed, but I didn't know the exact local font names for their different style/weight variants. The way you can do it, is with `Local Font Access API` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Local_Font_Access_API). I hope it will help someone